# How do I implement a JavaScript-style callback?

Tags: callback, rust

I'm trying to implement a JavaScript-style callback. I have an application that uses a library (both are mine) and I need the application to be able to pass a closure or function to a method in the library, which then spawns a thread and inside the thread when a condition is met it will call the callback.

main.rs

```
fn main(){
    welcome_message();
    mylib::connect(|| println!("Connected to service! Please enter a command. (hint: help)\n\n"));
    loop {
        match prompt_input() {
            true => {},
            false => break,
        }
    }
}
```

lib.rs

```
pub fn connect<F>(resolve: F) -> (mpsc::Sender<Message>, mpsc::Receiver<Message>)
    where F: Fn()
{

    ...

    let receive_loop = Thread::scoped(move || {
        for response in receiver.incoming_messages::<Message>(){
            let json_string = match response.unwrap() {
                Message::Text(txt) => txt,
                _ => "".to_string(),
            };
            let message = json::Json::from_str(json_string.as_slice());
            let message_json = message.unwrap();
            if message_json.is_object() {
                let ref something = receiver_tx;
                let obj = message_json.as_object().unwrap();
                let something_json = obj.get("lsri").unwrap();
                let something = something_json.to_string().replace("\"", "");
                match something.as_slice() {
                    "service#connected" => resolve(),
                    _ => println!("{}", type),
                }
            } else {
                println!("Invalid service response");
            }
        }
    });

    ...

}
```

Error

```
src/lib.rs:54:24: 54:38 error: the trait `core::marker::Send` is not implemented for the type `F` [E0277]
src/lib.rs:54     let receive_loop = Thread::scoped(move || {
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/lib.rs:54:24: 54:38 note: `F` cannot be sent between threads safely
src/lib.rs:54     let receive_loop = Thread::scoped(move || {
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It doesn't need to be a closure that I pass, I could pass a function too. It doesn't need any arguments or return types, but I could add some dummy ones if that helps. I am VERY open to suggestions of other methods or ways to accomplish the same goal.

I have tried using:

- Thread::spawn
- FnMut()
- Arc::new(resolve) (with implementation of .clone())
- Arc::new(Mutex::new(resolve)) (with implementation of .lock())
- Searching Google for examples
- Reading the Rust book in it's entirety
- Searching the error message for examples
- All of the above in various configurations

Is this possible with Rust? Is there a better way?

Thank you for your time in advance.

**Solution:**

For anyone finding this in the future, per the instructions of the answer below I changed the signature of `connect` to the following, which allowed the callback to be passed into the thread.

```
pub fn connect<'a, T, F>(resolve: F) -> (mpsc::Sender<Message>, mpsc::Receiver<Message>)
    where T: Send + 'a, F: FnOnce() -> T, F: Send + 'a
```

Comment: Note that the Rust style is 4-space indents.

Comment: Ah, I can fix that if you'd like, It is in my code, though for readability and spacing in the question I reduced it to two

Comment: It would greatly help if you could produce an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), especially one that compiles (or has the appropriate error) in the [Playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/). Right now, your code uses `type` as a variable name, which isn't valid Rust.

Comment: That was an edit in the question as well to hide the name of the actual variable. Will fix and look into the MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try marking your `F` with the same restrictions as [Thread::scoped](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.Thread.html#method.scoped):

```
fn scoped<'a, T, F>(f: F) -> JoinGuard<'a, T> 
    where T: Send + 'a, F: FnOnce() -> T, F: Send + 'a
```

specifically, bounding the type with the `Send` trait should clear the immediate error of

> the trait `core::marker::Send` is not implemented for the type `F`

Comment: That solved that issue and is immensely helpful. Thank you. Now on to the next issue, which is _very closely_ related to this one, but should be a quick answer. Should I create a new question on SO, or add it as an edit to my post? It has to do with the calling of the callback in the `match` block.